# How To Return First And Last Element Of Json

Tags: java, json, gson

Using gson how can I return the first and last element from my json so I get the data in this format?

```
System.out.println("Student: BobGoblin - result: 59");
```

I have tried this, but it still returns the full JSON object

```
JsonObject jsonObject = new Gson().fromJson(content.toString(), JsonObject.class);
return jsonObject.get(domain) + " - " + jsonObject.get(result.toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all: toJson converts something *to* json. You want to convert json to some kind of object. So use `fromJson` instead.

Second build an object where you can put that data into. There are plenty examples on the manual site for gson: https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md

Let me code that for you. It's not that hard:

```
import java.util.Map;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class GsonTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

      Gson gson = new Gson();

      String json = "{\"name\":\"Bog\", \"foo\":\"bar\", \"result\": 59}";

      // Using a map
      @SuppressWarnings( "unchecked" )
      Map<String,Object> map = gson.fromJson( json, Map.class );
      System.out.println( "Name: " + map.get( "name" ) + " result: " + map.get( "result" ) );

      // Better: using an object
      Student student = gson.fromJson( json, Student.class );
      System.out.println( "Name: " + student.name + " result: " + student.result );

    }

    public static class Student {
        public String name;
        public String foo;
        public int result;
    }
}
```

which will result in:

```
Name: Bog result: 59.0
Name: Bog result: 59
```

The general Method is: Take the json String and put it in some kind of java object. Then access that java object to get to your data.

Note that you get more control over the kind of data you will receive using the second method. Since json doesn't specify the datatype the parser guesses `float/double` for age while it uses `int` in the second example because the class said so.

Comment: i also tried the fromJSON sample that I saw, but if i do a writeln for jsonObject.get(domain); jsonObject.get(result.toString()); it will write null

Comment: So there you have an example. Its not that hard.